# Track messageType object in DTM with single page application style functionality

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

On our site we have a message interface that allows users to submit messages to different queues. This is done with a single web page application setup. They can submit multiple messages (one at a time) if they wish.

We do this with modal windows and ajax, changing the content of the window to a success message when the ajax returns successfully.

We would like to track which queue they are submitting the data to along with some other information on the page.

Normally we load a new page for confirmation pages, and so just submit this data in the `digitalData` object we are making on each page with the `_satellite.pageBottom();` event called at the bottom of the page.

I was told that if we updated our `digitalData` object that was already on the page with this data, and then called `_satellite.track();` it would take the new data and add it as part of the tracked events for that page.

I was worried that this would look like another page hit, or that it wouldn't work at all. The person I was talking to didn't really give me any real feeling of confidence in his answer.

What would be the best approach for sending these objects to our DTM to tack this type of user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

_satellite.track() will work for this and will not send a new page view to Analytics unless you set it up to. You just need to setup a direct call rule. Then you just call it using _satellite.track('msgQueued'), or whatever your name is, and use the UI to pick up all the digitalData variables you need. In the analytics section of DTM you make sure you use the option for s.tl() call to avoid the additional page view.